# Inability to capture output from "dd" using backticks

Tags: perl, unix, solaris, backticks, dd

I've been working with a very old Solaris system and not in a position to add more modules to make my life easier, and I'm working with a number of scripts that use various command line options.

The majority of what I'm working on is, in fact working, but I'm coming up with something that I just can't seem to get round.

I'm pulling data from a tape using the "dd" command and need to capture the output to ascertain if I'm experiencing any tape read errors.

("comment()" is a subroutine that I've already created)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
$| = 1;     #disable output buffering

$tarfile = '/mnt/test/tmp/12345.tar';

@tapeinfo = `dd if=/dev/rmt/1cbn of=$tarfile`;

foreach(@tapeinfo){
#Check to ensure that we're not getting read errors
 $result = index($_,'read: I/O error');
 if ($result &lt; 0){
  #No read error, log result
  comment($_);
  } else {
  # read error, terminate
  comment("Terminating due to tape read error : $_");
  last; #exit loop if error is found
  }
}
#terminate with logging
```

When the script runs, I see "123+0 records in, 123+0 records out" being posted to the terminal screen, but my loop where the @tapeinfo doesn't seem to be testing against at all. I don't get either an error or a logging of the information.

Am I missing something dreadfully simple here??

Comment: By the by, your use of `index` to find a match looks like you want to use C rather than Perl. The idiomatic, slightly wasteful, approach would be to use a regex; `if (m%read: I/O error%) {` ...

Answer (score 9):

`dd` outputs to stderr while backticks capture stdout. This is documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators):

> Because backticks do not affect standard error, use shell file
>   descriptor syntax (assuming the shell supports this) if you care to
>   address this. To capture a command's STDERR and STDOUT together:
>
> ```
> $output = `cmd 2>&1`;
> ```

You can do:

`my @tapeinfo = qx( dd if=/dev/rmt/1cbn of=$tarfile 2>&1 );`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `strace` or whatever that system provides to find out definitely, but the two likely options are

- The output is sent to STDERR. You could address this by merging STDERR and STDOUT (`2>&1`).
- The output is sent to the tty. Not much can be done about that.